# Taller curvearrowright

Tags: relation-symbols

Would there be a way to make `\curvearrowright` taller? I can't find any symbol which matches this, but `\curvearrowright` is just too short. I want to use it to represent an action by an algebraic object on whatever it acts on. I was hoping for something about the size of `\cap` with the approximate curve of `\curvearrowright`.

Using the `scalerel` package, `\vstretch{1.5}{\hstretch{0.8}{\curvearrowright}}` looks perfect to me in terms of shape:

[image]

But I don't like how the line isn't the same thickness throughout anymore. Does anybody have any better ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know a standard symbol like that, but you can always build your own, for example with TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\acts}{\mathrel{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\f@size pt, y=\f@size pt]
        \draw[->] (0,0) arc[start angle=180, x radius=.4, y radius=.7, end angle=0];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\(G \acts X\)
\end{document}
```